# OS X terminal copy and rename one file with backward sequential day 60 times

Tags: date, batch-rename

I'm looking for a script to copy and rename one single file in a folder 60 times with backward sequential day in OS X

For example `diary.list` becomes

`20140320_diary.list`

`20140319_diary.list`

`20140318_diary.list`

`20140317_diary.list`

`20140316_diary.list`

....

`20140120_diary.list`

I know this simple script to copy and rename with previous date to it

```
cp diary.list $(date -v -1d '+%Y%m%d')_diary.list
```

But how do I put `-1d` in a loop so that it repeats 60 times?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in `seq 1 60`; do cp -v diary.list $(date -v -`echo $i`d '+%Y%m%d')_diary.list ; done
```

Omit -v from the cp command to quiet output.